# How can I loop this PL/SQL statement so that it plots multiple markers on my Google map?

Tags: javascript, oracle, google-maps, plsql, oracle-apex

I am using an Oracle 12c database, APEX 5 and the Google Maps API.

This PL/SQL statement takes the coordinates of each sighting from the `sighting` table and plots it on the map. I create the map before I enter the loop because I want to use the same map for all of the markers. The javascript functions are called in a dynamic page load action.

```
DECLARE
  l_lng NUMBER;
  l_lat NUMBER;
  l_id  NUMBER(5,0);

htp.print('<html>');
htp.print('<head>');
htp.print('<style>
    #map {
            width: 500px;
            height: 400px;
        }
    </style>
');

htp.print('
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
    <script>
        function initializeMap() {
              var myLatLng = {
                  lng: -4.083020,
                  lat: 50.315239
              };

              map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
                  zoom: 15,
                  center: myLatLng
              });          
        }
    </script>
');

BEGIN
  FOR sighting_rec IN
  (SELECT id, species_id FROM sighting ORDER BY id
  )
  LOOP
    SELECT sighting.id,
      t.x Longitude,
      t.y Latitude
    INTO l_id,
      l_lng,
      l_lat
    FROM sighting,
      TABLE(sdo_util.getvertices(sighting.location)) t
    WHERE sighting.id = sighting_rec.id;

    htp.print(' 
        <script>
            function initializeMarkers() {
                var myLatLng = {
                    lng: ' || l_lng || ',
                    lat: ' || l_lat || '
                };

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatLng,
                map: map,
                title: ' || l_id || '
                });
            }
        </script>
    ');
    htp.print('</head>');

  END LOOP;
    htp.print('
    <body>
        <div id="map"></div>
    </body>
    ');
    htp.print('</html>');
END;
```

This only outputs one marker:
[image: Only outputs one marker]

Including a `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_lat || ',' || l_lng);` after `WHERE sighting.id = sighting_rec.id;` shows that all records are being retrieved:

```
-4.083592,50.31548
-4.083639,50.315456
-4.083714,50.315475
```

I can't work out why only the first marker is being plotted! I think that each time the loop iterates, the marker gets recreated. I have tried to use `var ' || l_id || ' = new google.maps.Marker`, but that caused the map to not load at all! Any guidance would be great!

This is the HTML output when sent to the browser:

```
        <script>


            function initializeMarkers() {

                    var myLatLng = {
                        lng: -4.083592,
                        lat: 50.31548
                    };

                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: myLatLng,
                    map: map,
                    title: 12
                    });

          }
        </script>
        <script>


            function initializeMarkers() {

                    var myLatLng = {
                        lng: -4.083639,
                        lat: 50.315456
                    };

                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: myLatLng,
                    map: map,
                    title: 13
                    });

          }
        </script>
        <script>


            function initializeMarkers() {

                    var myLatLng = {
                        lng: -4.083714,
                        lat: 50.315475
                    };

                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: myLatLng,
                    map: map,
                    title: 14
                    });

          }
        </script>
```

Comment: What does the HTML look like that is sent to the browser?  It looks like you only create one marker in the `initializeMarkers` function. Javascript only allows a single function with that name, if I am reading your code correctly, you are creating a copy of that function for each marker you would like displayed.

Comment: The HTML outputs 3 markers, which i'll put in to question due to the character limit

Comment: @geocodezip I've added the output to the bottom of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you have multiple `initializeMarkers` routines, only one will be called, which one will depend on the browser.  Create a single function which adds all the markers (and call it somewhere, I don't see where you are calling either the `intializeMap` or `initializeMarkers` routines, but if you are getting a map with a marker, that must be happening somewhere).

```
htp.print('<script>
    function initializeMarkers() {');

BEGIN
  FOR sighting_rec IN
  (SELECT id, species_id FROM sighting ORDER BY id
  )
  LOOP
    SELECT sighting.id,
      t.x Longitude,
      t.y Latitude
    INTO l_id,
      l_lng,
      l_lat
    FROM sighting,
      TABLE(sdo_util.getvertices(sighting.location)) t
    WHERE sighting.id = sighting_rec.id;

    htp.print(' 
            var myLatLng = {
                lng: ' || l_lng || ',
                lat: ' || l_lat || '
            };

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatLng,
            map: map,
            title: ' || l_id || '
            });');

  END LOOP;

htp.print('}
    </script>
');
htp.print('</head>');
```